# How to use AssetContainer with AssetManager in babylonJS?

Tags: babylonjs

I'm using BabylonJS for some 3D project, While setting up a scene I can load up multiple GLB files using `AssetManager`, after all the loading tasks has been done, i can find the meshes in the scene, but cannot find the meshes that should be loaded towards the `AssetContainer`, how can i access the `AssetContainer` after loading the meshes to `AssetContainer` using `AssetManager.addContainerTask`.

Answer (score 0):

After `containerTask = assetManager.addContainerTask` use:

```
containerTask.onSuccess = (task) => {
    const container = task.loadedContainer;
}
```